# How to create an HTML5 widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

any idea. how i can make something like a live news widget or similar Twitter widget for latest  tweets. i appreciate for any example or samples

content 1 -- move down -- wait for 2 sec and move

content 2 -- move down -- wait for 2 sec and move

content 3 -- move down -- wait for 2 sec and move

```
<MARQUEE behavior="scroll" direction="down" scrollamount="3" SCROLLDELAY=1000>Hello Mike</MARQUEE>
<MARQUEE behavior="scroll" direction="down" SCROLLDELAY=800>Hello John</MARQUEE>
<MARQUEE behavior="scroll" direction="down" SCROLLDELAY=700>Hello Jeff</MARQUEE>
```

i have wrote some marquee to show wat i want. the problem with marque is that cant bring it in professional way. i just need 1 text to come and move down with a wait time of 2 seconds then other word comes and previous   move down automatically

Comment: Please review [ask].  Your question is too broad.

Comment: @qwel niff Are you looking for something like https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/overview.html#?

Comment: @10101010 yes bro. a similar to that. but i want to make my own which i can put on my website to display content comes from my db

Comment: If you let us know where you are stuck or add some code to your question we can really help you out very well. At the moment your question is too broad, which would require people to explain a lot of stuff.

Comment: @10101010 have wrote some code as seen and how i like it to be. really stressing my head. this thing similar to rss feed widget

Comment: Have you tried making a list of div's and scrolling them with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing a Web Component.

That is the built-in way to create a "widget".

https://coherent-labs.com/posts/web-components/

You should write them in JS files.
Avoid using HTML Import since it is deprecated and will soon not be in any browser.
Consider using ES6 template literals instead of `<template>` tags.